# Javascript - compare two array of objects based on their length

Tags: javascript

I have 2 array of objects and 2 if conditions

```
    if(JSON.stringify(this.updatedData) !== JSON.stringify(this.originalData) && this.updatedData.length === this.originalData.length) {            
        this.customAttributes = editedCustomAttributes;
        this.customAttributes.forEach(function (element) {
          element.action = "edit";
        });
    }
      
    if (JSON.stringify(this.updatedData) !== JSON.stringify(this.originalData) && his.updatedData.length !== this.originalData.length) {
        const items = this.updatedData.filter(item => item.attributeId == null);
        items.forEach(function (element) {
          element.action = "add";
        });
    }
```

While editing a grid row, `originalData` and `updatedData` will have the same length hence the first if condition executes. While I am adding new row, `updatedData` length will be more than `originalData` hence the 2nd if condition executes.

But I have a situation where a user can add a new row and edit an existing row at once. At that particular scenario, I need to execute both the if conditions and I stuck there. Any suggestions will be appretiated. Thanks.

Comment: Can the user add more than one row at once? And is the new added row always pushed to the end of the `updatedData` array?

Comment: Yes for both questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as follows:

```js
function check() {
  const original = JSON.stringify(originalData)

  if (originalData.length !== updatedData.length) {
    // If lengths are not equal then new rows were added
    addedAction()

    // Check the two arrays again without those new rows
    const newRows = updatedData.length - originalData.length
    if (JSON.stringify(updatedData.slice(0, -newRows)) !== original) {
      editedAction()
    }

  } else if (JSON.stringify(updatedData) !== original) {
    editedAction()
  }

}
```

The `addedAction()` and `editedAction()` functions are just what will happen in response to an edit or addition.

In the case where an addition and an edit is performed `addedAction()` will be executed first due to diffirence in lengths. Then `originalData` will be checked against a portion of the `updatedData` and the `editedAction()` function will be executed if they are not the same after removing the newly added rows.

Here is an example with the three cases:

```js
function check() {
  const original = JSON.stringify(originalData)

  if (originalData.length !== updatedData.length) {
    // If lengths are not equal then new rows were added
    addedAction()

    // Check the two arrays again without those new rows
    const newRows = updatedData.length - originalData.length
    if (JSON.stringify(updatedData.slice(0, -newRows)) !== original) {
      editedAction()
    }

  } else if (JSON.stringify(updatedData) !== original) {
    editedAction()
  }

  console.log('')
}

function editedAction() {
  console.log('Edited')
}

function addedAction() {
  console.log('Added')
}

console.log('First case:')
let originalData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]
let updatedData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'd' }, { name: 'asd' }]
check()

console.log('Second case:')
originalData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]
updatedData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'TEST' }]
check()

console.log('Third case:')
originalData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]
updatedData = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: '123' }, { name: 'test2' }]
check()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }
```